# Selenium Compare Web table with Excel data

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I need to compare Web table with downloaded excel file. 
Excel data have numeric value which is formatted in excel (example 523010735055.256    formatted to in excel $ 523,011. 
I need to validate  $ 523,011 with UI value. 
How can I do equal both the table.
Image for reference [1]: https://i.imgur.com/a/OWXS7pJ "image"

I have used  DataFormatter as most of the other post suggested for similar question. yet its not working.

I have found other way to solve this problem without

```
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    System.out.print(value + " ");

                    break;
```

How can I change above code in this below manner

```
                    String val1 = null;
                    Double numvalue1 = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    Long longValue1 = numvalue1.longValue();
                    val1 = new String(longValue1.toString());
                    BigDecimal convertres1 = new BigDecimal(val1);
                    String aarwavalue1 = (convertres1.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR) + "");
```

Code
             waitForElementPresent(driver, 30, mstrframe);

```
        // To locate table.
        WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@id,'ReportGridStyle_forRW')])[2]//tbody"));
        // To locate rows of table.
        List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        // To calculate no of rows In table.
        int rows_count = rows_table.size();
        // Loop will execute till the last row of table.
        for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {
            // To locate columns(cells) of that specific row.
            List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            // To calculate no of columns (cells). In that specific row.
            int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
            System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
            // Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
            for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
                // To retrieve text from that specific cell.
                String celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
                System.out
                        .println("Cell Value of row number " + row + " and column number " + column + " Is " + celtext);
            }

        }
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\resources\\excelfiles\\Bas Outline Mode Report.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        // Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
        XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        // Data formatter
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        // Find number of rows in excel file
        // Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sh1.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    System.out.print(value + " ");

                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Output

```
    Number of cells In Row 0 are 5
    Cell Value of row number 0 and column number 0 Is DataGrouping
    Cell Value of row number 0 and column number 1 Is RWAExposureType
    Cell Value of row number 0 and column number 2 Is AA RWA ex 1.06x
    Cell Value of row number 0 and column number 3 Is AA RWA
    Cell Value of row number 0 and column number 4 Is SA RWA
    Number of cells In Row 1 are 5
    Cell Value of row number 1 and column number 0 Is Credit Risk
    Cell Value of row number 1 and column number 1 Is Available For Sale
    Cell Value of row number 1 and column number 2 Is $ 449,454
    Cell Value of row number 1 and column number 3 Is $ 476,421
    Cell Value of row number 1 and column number 4 Is $ 264,503
    Number of cells In Row 2 are 4
    Cell Value of row number 2 and column number 0 Is Contingent
    Cell Value of row number 2 and column number 1 Is $ 113,262
    Cell Value of row number 2 and column number 2 Is $ 120,057
    Cell Value of row number 2 and column number 3 Is $ 258,508
    Number of cells In Row 3 are 4
    Cell Value of row number 3 and column number 0 Is Total
    Cell Value of row number 3 and column number 1 Is $ 562,715
    Cell Value of row number 3 and column number 2 Is $ 596,478
    Cell Value of row number 3 and column number 3 Is $ 523,011
    Number of cells In Row 4 are 5
    Cell Value of row number 4 and column number 0 Is Total
    Cell Value of row number 4 and column number 1 Is  
    Cell Value of row number 4 and column number 2 Is $ 562,715
    Cell Value of row number 4 and column number 3 Is $ 596,478
    Cell Value of row number 4 and column number 4 Is $ 523,011




    Data Grouping RWA Exposure Type ( $ M ) AA RWA ex 1.06x ( $ M ) AA RWA ( $ M ) SA RWA 
    Credit Risk 5.62715E+11 5.96478E+11 5.23011E+11 
    Available For Sale 4.49454E+11 4.76421E+11 2.64503E+11 
    Contingent 1.13262E+11 1.20057E+11 2.58508E+11 
    Total 5.62715E+11 5.96478E+11 5.23011E+11 
    5/2/2019 1:16:59 PM
```

POI change to 4.1.0

```
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {   
                case NUMERIC:
                    cell.getNumericCellValue();                 
                    String value =formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    System.out.print(value + " ");
                    break;                      
                case STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: Just tested. `DataFormatter` of `apache poi`version `4.1.0` supports `formatCode="\$\ #,##0,," `. So this issue is not reproducible for me.

Comment: @Axel Richer please read edited code

Comment: Using `DataFormatter`is the correct way. As said for me `DataFormatter` works for number 523010735055.256 formatted in excel using `$ #,##0,,` format pattern, which shows as $ 523,011. Then `formatter.formatCellValue(cell)` results in exactly " $ 523,011" for that cell.

Comment: @AxelRichter I was using poi 3.17 when I change to poi 4.1.0 I get error in my framework  else if (Cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)  "CELL_TYPE_STRING  cannot be resloved" how can I over come this

Comment: @AxelRichter I have over come all problem with change to 4.1.0 but still data formatter is not working with 4.1.0 version too

Comment: What format pattern is used in your `Excel` to make 523010735055.256 to $ 523,011? As said for me `DataFormatter` works if format code is `$ #,###,,` or `$ #,##0,,`.

Comment: @AxelRichter "$ "#,##0,,;($#,##0,,)  this is excel format

Comment: Format code `"$ "#,##0,,;"($ "#,##0,,);` works. Note the semicolon after the pattern for negative numbers. Format code `"$ "#,##0,,;"($ "#,##0,,);;` works as well: `Format for positive numbers;Format for negative numbers;Format for zeros;Format for text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `DataFormatter` needs a semicolon after the last sub pattern if multiple patterns for positive numbers, for negative numbers, for zeros and/or for text is used and not all four sub patterns are given.

Example: `Format for positive numbers;Format for negative numbers;Format for zeros;Format for text` works but `Format for positive numbers;Format for negative numbers` does not work and needs to be `Format for positive numbers;Format for negative numbers;`. Note the semicolon after the pattern for negative numbers.

This is different to `Excel` since there the last semicolon is not needed.

If we know this we can do the following:

Sheet example:

[image]

Number format pattern in `Excel` is `"$ "#,##0,,;"($ "#,##0,,\)`.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

class ReadExcelSpecialNumberFormat {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelSpecialNumberFormat.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

  CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = creationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
    String dataFormatString = cellStyle.getDataFormatString();
    if (dataFormatString != null && dataFormatString.contains(";"))
     cellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat(dataFormatString+";"));
    String cellContent = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
    System.out.print(cellContent + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.1.0$ javac -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* ReadExcelSpecialNumberFormat.java 
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.1.0$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* ReadExcelSpecialNumberFormat 
Data Grouping  Amount 1 ($ M) Amount 2 ($ M) Amount 3 ($ M) 
Credit Risk $ 772.314 $ 913.546 $ 812.453 
Available For Sale ($ 685.104) $ 800.603 $ 830.131 
Contingent $ 509.480 $ 524.524 ($ 629.797) 
Total $ 596.689 $ 2.238.674 $ 1.012.786
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback @AxcelRicher.
Dataformatter is not working in this case.

I will used below code for resolve to problem now

```
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {   
                case NUMERIC:
                    //cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    Double value= cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    Long longValue1 = value.longValue();
                    String val1 = new String(longValue1.toString());
                    BigDecimal convertres1 = new BigDecimal(val1);
                    String aarwavalue1 = (convertres1.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR) + "");
                    System.out.print(aarwavalue1 + "\t ");
                    break;                      
                case STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
```